# Is it possible to extract a disconnect reason from python server side flask socketio?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

Creating a flask socketio instance on the backend, which we use to send data to the front end. I have no issue detecting a disconnect:

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Socket has been disconnected!')
```

but I can't figure out how to pull one of the set reasons on the backend. We have several different sockets and I want to see all of the socket disconnect issues to better understand where present and future problems come from. The reasons are listed here on the Socket.io documentation, in JS:

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/#disconnect

but there's nothing in the flask socketio, where the disconnect function doesn't have an argument. Has anyone successfully done this on the server side in python? Doesn't seem like a set way in the flask socketio...any workaround?

Thanks in advance.